# Grep with range and pass three filters

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, sed, awk

I have a file `sample.txt`

```
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
ord:RAM      SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:UU
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
```

where I am filtering orders based on keywords like `ord:chandru` and `key:ZZ` if find these occurrences, I will remove the orders starting from hyphen to hyphen to give output like this

```
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
```

Comment: The middle section was removed but I don't know why, based on your explanation. Do you only want sections that look exactly like the remaining ones, or all sections that have `ord:chandru` or (or and?) `KEY:ZZ` regardless of whatever else is in them??

Comment: the file contains many names like ord:vijay and KEY:VV like but my filters are these ord:chandru and key:ZZ if i get these then print from hyphen to hyphen to new.txt

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU `awk` I'd suggest something like this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="-+\n"} $0=="" || /ord:chandru/ && /KEY:ZZ/ {ORS=RT; print}' sample.txt
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
```

The `$0==""` just forces printing of empty records (which is how the first line of your file will be interpreted, if you consider records to be delimited by strings of hyphens).

---

If you *don't* have `gawk`, then really the only difference is that you can't easily capture the record separator - in the sample you have provided that's not a big issue since it is a fixed string. So for example with `mawk`:

```
mawk 'BEGIN{RS="-------------\n"; ORS=RS} $0=="" || /ord:chandru/ && /KEY:ZZ/ {print}' sample.txt
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
-------------
```

Comment: I am sorry i have normal old awk and soon after i need to test this in solaris BOX.

Comment: @shekhar see edited answer

Comment: @shekhar in that case, I am afraid your question is off topic on [ubuntu.se], so I migrated it here. Ask Ubuntu only deals with Ubuntu (which ships with GNU awk), and you seem to be running something else.  And if it also needs to work on Solaris, that is again different. So please edit your question and clarify what OS this needs to work on.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty reliable

```
$ sed -n '1p; /ord:chandru/ {             
N                                           
N
/KEY:ZZ/{
N
/ord:chandru.*\n.*\n.*KEY:ZZ.*\n---.*/p
}
}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-n` don't print until we ask for something
- `1p` print the first line, assuming that will give us a line of hyphens (thereafter, we only print trailing lines of hyphens)
- `/ord:chandru/` find the pattern
- `N` read the next line to allow us to use the `\n` character to represent newlines
- `p` print the matched lines

Comment: Thanks Zanna my fault i didnot mentioned sometime ROWS will increase or decrease,  so is there any dynamic way not passing N to script only with filters and hypen it should filterout.

Comment: surely there is @shekhar but I don't know that way :)

Comment: You can easily do this without `N`... just save the data lines in the `H`old space and e`x`change on each delimiter, test and delete if no match.

Comment: @don_crissti I better go study...

Comment: take your time - it's not that hard once you figure out how the hold space works - it's pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

Using **awk**:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="-------------"};/KEY:ZZ/&&/ord:chandru/{print RS$0}' sample.txt|egrep -v "^ *$"
```

Output:

```
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:Z    
-------------
ord:chandru  SAM 
    XY       DUPL
    KEY:ZZ
```

Comment: how about this :  awk 'BEGIN{RS="-------------"}; /KEY:ZZ/ord:chandru/ {print "-------------"$0}' sample.txt

Comment: I am getting the error:awk: Line   L  H  S  C  N  D   cannot have more than 199 fields.
 The input line number is 393. The file is text.txt.
 The source line number is 1.

Comment: Is that the exact error message?  Can you post the exact awk line that you are using as well as a sample of the text that may be different from what is in the sample text in your original question?  I can't reproduce the error with the text in your question, or any variations that I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   /^ord:/,/^--*$/!b
   H; /^ord:/h
   /^--*$/!d; g
   /^ord:chandru[ ]/!d
   /\n[ ]*KEY:ZZ\n--*$/!d
'  sample.txt
```

Brief summary:
  `/../,/../` => is the range operator to select a range of lines , like in your case from `/ord:/ to /----/`.

We squirrel sway these ranges (a range at a time) into the hold area. Then when we are at the end of range `/---/`, we know the time has come to select or reject this particular range based on the the criteria that `a) /ord:chandru/ && b) /key:ZZ/'